# How to set up this transition matrix?

Tags: probability, statistics

An insurance company classifies its drivers into three groups. N(No accident), O (one accident), and M (more than one accident). The probability that an N driver after one year is 44%, that the N driver will become an O driver is 28% and that an N driver will become a M driver is 28%. An O driver cannot become an N driver but there is 49% that an O driver will remain 0 driver. An M driver must remain an M driver.

1. Find the transition matrix describing this situation [N, O, M].

Answer (score 0):

My attempt:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.44 &  0.28 & 0.28 \\ 
0 & 0.49 & 0.51 \\ 
 0 & 0  &1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Yes, you choose the rows to add up to one. Some textbooks choose columns to add up to one, so that state vectors look like a typical one column vector. For theoretical purposes, it shouldn't really matter